# How to create fixed actionbar in android and launch new activities below it

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I'm developing an app that uses ActionBarSherlock for action bar. I want to make this action bar fixed across all the actions and want to launch any activities generated below this action bar.

Like, if user click on any of the action bar items, next activity should be rendered just below it (In the presentation area).

I also want to have swipy tabs below the action bar (that should not be the part of our action bar but should be generated by clicking on any of the action bar item).

I would really appreciate if somebody could share any pointers for me to start with.

I read many documents and tried few samples but instead of rendering new activity below action bar, I come up with activity launched in entire screen!!

Please help.

Comment: Maybe `Fragment`s fit better for you.

Comment: What you are describing can be done with a single `Activity` which hosts the `ActionBar` and has a 'placeholder' layout. You'd then create different `Fragments` in the area below the `ActionBar` rather than attempt to use `Activities`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't put an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) inside another Activity

You can use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) inside your Activity and replace the existing Fragment with another one.

If you are targeting API <11 Then you need to use a [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) that contains [support Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

So using your swipey tabs example, those tabs would be Fragments managed by an Adapter which deals with a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

[Here's an example in the ActionBarSherlock samples](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java)

I'm pasting the static inner class just to be sure to keep it here if the link dies

```
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final TabHost mTabHost;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final String tag;
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            tag = _tag;
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private final Context mContext;

        public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            v.setMinimumWidth(0);
            v.setMinimumHeight(0);
            return v;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mTabHost = tabHost;
        mViewPager = pager;
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Unfortunately when TabHost changes the current tab, it kindly
        // also takes care of putting focus on it when not in touch mode.
        // The jerk.
        // This hack tries to prevent this from pulling focus out of our
        // ViewPager.
        TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
        int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
        widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Benoit for quick and helpful answer.